# Mirror object with animation

Tags: animation, objects, mirror

I am making an aircraft for Flight Simulator and I need basically get the flaps from one wing copied to the other wing with the animations, if it is possible, how can I do it ?

[image: plane model without mirrored flaps]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the Mirror modifier.

[image: Mirror Mod]

Object Mode: Select the flaps.
In the Properties panel, click the wrench icon.  Add Modifier, Mirror.

At the bottom, Mirror Object: select your plane object.

Axis will depend upon orientation of scene.
I believe X is the correct orientation in your image.

click Apply, and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

I meant ;

A- Put the cursor in the middle .

B- Change the pivot as 3D cursor .

C- Duplicate the requested object by using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

D- Press <kbd>S</kbd> while the object is selected then type `-1`

[image]

You will see the object as the following.

E- Press <kbd>R</kbd> then <kbd>X</kbd> after that 180.

[image]

This is the result .[image]

Comment: I hope it's clear now .

Comment: Instead of adding a new answer to clarify please edit the previous one. Only add different answers if you are presenting alternative solutions.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work with flap animations.

Answer (score -2):

I think that no need to use mirror, as you can duplicate the mesh by pressing "shift + D" then make a snap by pressing " S " then -1 .

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: Ok, repeat same exercise then execute the R, X, 180

Comment: I don't even know what that all means ? thanks for helping btw.